# MinimalCD - Strange input lag on certain keys `, ~, ´, and ¨

Tags: keyboard

I´ve just installed mini.iso Ubuntu 14.04 and there is some kind of international keyboard features that are causing me to need to double-tap ´ or `. If I use these keys and then immediately another key, I type characters such as ǘ or ó.

I´ve followed instructions to change my keyboard successfully to `qwerty` `US` and `standard` using the following console

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-data`

However, it´s still doing the delay (it is waiting to see if I will type an international character). How do I fix this?